# A page with custom parameters

Tags: 7

I have a page to do this:

```
Boats/
Boats/Veterans
Boats/Nine
Boats/Used
```

Where ['Veterans', 'Nine', 'Used'] would be the parameters passed into the URL!
I would like to use my page customize

> page--boats.tpl.php

This is a page theme. Currently, I have a white page.

How can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are asking about [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

what you need is to create an item which has a base of boats, and takes an argument.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['boats/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_boats',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );  
  return $items;
}
```